# Horizontal scroll on parent, vertical scroll on child

Tags: html, css, angular

I have one div container and another div inside container. I would like to add scrolling horizontal on parent (container div) and vertical on child to see the text inside those divs. Any help?

There is a stackblitz to show my problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t98oj8

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.text {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="text">
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify class `.one` with:

```
  /* ADDED */
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height:100%;
```

The width that you set in text should be set in the parent. And you need to set the height to 100% (instead of 300px), otherwise you ever see the end of your scroll block.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.one {
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px red solid;
  /* ADDED */
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height:100%;
}

.text {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="text">
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
            Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
            Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
            Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
            Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
            Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some
      text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
      Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text
      here. Some text here.
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he need horizontal scroll for outer div and vertical scroll for inner div

Comment: @GouthamHarshith And this is it. `container` scroll x and then `one` y.  *"scrolling horizontal on parent (container div) and vertical on child"* To do so the child need to be larger than parent.